# Is it possible to declare a global variable to be distributed to hot standby servers?

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to workaround the fact that PostgreSQL 9.5 does not support querying replication delay from hot standby (it's possible to query the delay from master server but I'm trying to avoid connecting the master server unless absolutely necessary). We're using hot standby replica servers as read-only servers for our web service and we want to ignore the server if it's delayed too much from the master server. For discussion sake, lets assume that strictly less than 5 second delay is okay when data is accessed via hot standby.

Is it possible to define a variable on the master server that's get replicated to slaves (hot standby replicas in async streaming mode)?

I'm currently having a single row and single column table for storing the global timestamp in the database and I inspect this timestamp before accessing other data via hot standby replica. And a script updates this timestamp every second on the master database. However, I cannot inspect the timestamp within a transaction or I'll get rolled back transactions hitting

```
40001 terminating connection due to conflict with recovery
User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.
In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
```

Is there any trick that can publish some data from master to hot standby servers that can be accessed while transaction is active? I don't need ability to rollback changes to this variable and it doesn't need to follow transactions (that is, it's okay that the value of this variable changes even while transaction in repeatable read isolation mode is active).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody has offered any solution in half a year so I assume **no solution is known**.

**I solved the problem with the transactions by using separate transaction for querying the global timestamp from replicated table.** In my case, it was enough to create connection, begin a transaction, query the timestamp, commit the transaction and then check the timestamp. If the delay is not too high, continue the begin the real transaction, do whatever the transaction needs to do (remember, this must be true read-only transaction) and finally commit the transaction.

This way I don't need to have any extra connections but I need to create one additional transaction just for checking the timestamp. Because the table with the timestamp only has one column and one row, checking the value is always fast, though.